# "! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]" when trying to compile file with two tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, includegraphics

This works fine if I only use the first tikzpicture, not sure what goes wrong.

Here's the M(N)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{minipage}
\hspace{5mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.south west)+(2cm,5cm)$) {
     \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
};
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.south west)+(2cm,10cm)$) {
     \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply forgot an `\end{tikzpicture}` before the second `\begin{tikzpicture}`. Alternatively you can drop the second `\begin{tizpicture}`. And you do not need to load `graphicx` when you load `tikz`, `tikz` will do that for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{minipage}
\hspace{5mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.south west)+(2cm,5cm)$) {
     \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
};
  \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.south west)+(2cm,10cm)$) {
     \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```